# Неправильная установка времени cookie

Tags: php, cookie

```
setCookie('uhash', $param['hash'], time() + 3600, '/');
```

Почему кука устанавливается не на 1 час, а на 3-5 секунд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а вот это '/' вам зачем?
попробуйте без нее

Comment: @Ale_x, чтобы кука устанавливалась для всего сайта.

Comment: так по умолчанию она будет действовать на весь сайт